# Function implementation in keras tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I´ve got three tensors shape `(n,1) T,r,E` and I wanted to implement a function that calculates: `sum(i,j) (T[j] < T[i]) (r[j] > r[i]) E[j]`.
How can I proceed?

This is what I´ve got

```py
#tensor examples
T=K.constant([1,4,5])
r=K.constant([.8,.3,.7])
E=K.constant([1,0,1])

# cartesian product of T to compare element wise
c = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(T, T, indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
cartesian_T = tf.reshape(c, (-1, 2))

# cartesian product of r to compare elemento wise
r = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(r, r, indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
cartesian_r = tf.reshape(r, (-1, 2))

# TO DO: 
# compare the two columns in cartesian T and cast to integer 1/0 if  
# second column in T less/greater than first column in T => return tensor


# compare the two columns in cartesian E and cast to integer 1/0 if  
# second column in r greater/less than first column in r => return tensor

# multiply previous tensors by a broadcasted version of E, then do K.sum()
```

Do you think I'm on the right track? What would you suggest to implement this?

Comment: What output do you expect? `n*1` or `n*n`?

Comment: Should be a double

Comment: Can you give the output you expect in your example when `T=[1,4,5]` & `r=[.8,.3,.7]` & `E=[1,0,1]`?

Comment: Hi. I would expect 2.0 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

T=K.constant([1,4,5])
r=K.constant([.8,.3,.7])
E=K.constant([1,0,1])

T_new = tf.less(T[tf.newaxis,:],T[:,tf.newaxis])
r_new = tf.greater(r[tf.newaxis,:],r[:,tf.newaxis])
E_row,_ = tf.meshgrid(E, E)
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.boolean_mask(E_row,tf.logical_and(T_new,r_new)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

#print
2.0
```

Comment: Great! This it it! So grateful!

Comment: @JuanCastaño Please accept the answer if you have no question.

Comment: I've implemented the function; however when the tensors are big, it blows the memory; do you happen to think of a more performatic implementation?

Comment: @JuanCastaño How about the updated code? But I think the best way is to reduce batch size.

Comment: @JuanCastaño Did you use `tf.placeholder` to feed data?

Comment: Hi @giser_yugang. this I don´t know how to do. I don´t understand how will reducing batch size work, since I need to compare every T[j] to every T[i]. If I reduce batch size, then every T[j] will only be seing a subset of the T[i]. How should I implemente the calculations?

Comment: @JuanCastaño First,You should use GPU on hardware. Then if you feed data through `tf.placeholder`, you can easily control `batch_size`. There's no way if `T,r,E` are just separate matrice.